# Automatic redirection to https with port change

Tags: javascript, html

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954768/automatic-redirection-to-https), how can I change the port too?

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://')==0)
          window.location=window.location.href.replace('http://','https://');
```

For example, I want to change `http://localhost:8080/test/` to `https://localhost:8443/test/`, but right now it is only changing it to `https://localhost:8080/test/`

Is there a way to change it without hardcoding it? Currently I can hard code it like this `window.location = "https:localhost:8443/test/"`, but then I would have to do that for every unique page in test, and that could get to be a hassle.

Instead, is there a way to automatically change the port?

Comment: Right now, it is changing the http into https. I want to change the port too

Comment: Logic : check the `indexOf(':')` and then next string before `/` , if it is 8080 then replace with 8443. 
does this works?

Comment: `window.location=window.location.href.replace('http://','https://').replace(":8080", ":8443");`

Comment: I tried both of the two above comments. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconstruct href:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('http://')==0)
    window.location = 'https://'+window.location.hostname+':8443'+window.location.pathname+window.location.search;
```

Comment: @krikara it does work. Please post what error you are getting or where is error in redirect URL.

Comment: @krikara does your local server support HTTPs on port 8443? I just tested this on localhost with chrome and it worked well. Please learn how to use chrome developer tools to track Javascript errors with preserved log of them.

Comment: Yeah, it just brings me to a blank page with `about:blank` in the address bar.

Comment: @krikara i think you skipped part when i asked about Javascript console.

Comment: Yes, the page works on 8443. Your redirection doesn't work. Nothing is showing up in JS Console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40929/discussion-between-mris-kiseovs-and-krikara)