# force to SSL but exclude a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website and I have manage to force the http into https with this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

The problem is that I need to make 2 folder remain in http for example folder 1 and folder2.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(folder1|folder2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: what is the error and where are you applying this rule please provide the url you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer for my question but this is the solution that I need, and I got this from [automatic redirection to https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954768/automatic-redirection-to-https).

Thanks