# Redirect to HTTPS version of site?

Tags: http, https

I have a website that is currently being hosted on my college's server and I'm using some Javascript functionality that only works over HTTPS.
When I manually type in https://college.edu/myusername the site works just fine, but when typing in the address normally, it uses HTTP by default. 
Is there anyway for my web page to redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: What web server are you using? You can setup redirects from http to https in the web server's configuration.

Comment: It's my school's web server. The only access I have to the server is FTP to my specific user folder and access to those files.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954768/automatic-redirection-to-https